# Can I create a docker swarm network with few linux nodes and few windows node being part of the same overlay network?

Tags: docker-machine, docker-swarm

Is it possible to create a docker swarm network which contains a mix of Linux machines and windows machines each running their own containers on them ?

If yes, is there any way I can test such a setup on an Ubuntu desktop? Right now I use `docker-machine` to create multiple VM nodes on my Ubuntu and make them join the docker swarm. I need to test the setup with a mix of linux and windows nodes. I could not find any way to create a windows VM on a linux machine using `docker-machine`. What is the recommended way of testing a setup like this, if any at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com)? Docker Machine natively supports their platform: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/azure/.